# How do you show html text on a webpage, without it being counted as an element?

Tags: html

I want to show the HTML Element Tags (e.g. `<p>`) as plain text without being rendered. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for: `&lt;p&gt;`

The `&lt;` is the HTML entity representation of <.

The `&gt;` is the HTML entity representation of >.

Put them around the tag name you want to represent (in this case, p) and it should appear as <p>.